# Is spring data elastic search compatible with elasticsearch 2.3.1?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to connnect to `elasticsearch 2.3.1` with `spring-data-elasticsearch`, This worked fine with 1.6 but when I tried to connect with 2.3.1

I am getting the following exception

Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory.createParser(Ljava/io/Reader;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLParser

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Are you using a direct dependency on `spring-data-elasticsearch` or are you doing through `spring-boot-start-elasticsearch`?

Comment: I am using a direct dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress( new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(elasticSear‌​chHost), 9300));

and it works fine.